# What's wrong with storing the username and password in a cookie?

Tags: session, cookies, passwords, session-cookies

i'm reading an old applicaiton which saved the users usernamea nd password as a cookie - as a "rememeber me" feature. What's wrong with this approach, if anything?

i guess the password can be ferretted out if someone does a malicious javascript injection on one of the pages of the site, but any other security risk besides that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're transmitting the password, in the clear, over the Internet with every HTTP request.  If you're not using SSL, there's a risk of eavesdropping.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious one is if somebody intercepts the cookie when it's sent from the user's browser to your server, they can then impersonate that user. See [Firesheep](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Firesheep).

Answer (score 1):

The cookie is in the client, so anyone with access to the user's computer can read it.